# How to show only Parent Category name in single.php? (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

How to print only Parent Category name in single.php? (wordpress)

**My structure:**

Category A

-SubCategory X

- The post (article) is posted only to Subcategory X.
- I want to print only the name of "Category A".(without html tag).

Answer (score 0):

I think you try this code:
for me this is working............

```
<?php $parentscategory ="";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
$parentscategory .= ' <a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a>, ';
}
}
echo substr($parentscategory,0,-2); ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It didn't print anything. :(

Comment: I tried this:  `<?php echo get_category_parents( get_query_var('cat') , true , '' ); ?>` but i got:  Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $get_parent_cats = array(
        'parent' => '0' //get top level categories only
    ); 
    $all_cats = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );

    foreach( $all_categories as $single_category ){

       $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;
    }
```

?>

```
       echo '<li><a href=" ' . get_category_link( $catID ) . ' ">' . $single_category->name . '</a>'
```

Comment: Please dont write code only. Provide the explanation also. See on how to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).